# Shell Script Variable Quoting Problem

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an sh script that contains the line

```
$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'
```

I can not edit this script, but I need the eventual command line to be (equivalent to)

```
php -d include_path='/path/with spaces/dir' -r 'echo get_include_path();'
```

How can I achieve this?

---

Below is a script that demonstrates the problem.

```
#!/bin/sh

# shell script quoting problem demonstration

# I need to be able to set a shell variable with a command with 
# some options, like so
PHP_COMMAND="php -d 'include_path=/path/with spaces/dir'"
# then use PHP_COMMAND to run something in another script, like this:
$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'
# the above fails when executed. However, if you copy/paste the output
# from this line and run it in the CLI, it works!
echo "$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'"
php -d include_path='/path/with spaces/dir' -r 'echo get_include_path();'
# what's going on?

# this is also interesting
echo "\n--------------------"

# this works great, but only works if include_path doesn't need quoting
PHP_COMMAND="php -d include_path=/path/to/dir"
echo "$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'"
$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'

echo "\n--------------------"

# this one doesn't when run in the sh script, but again if you copy/paste 
# the output it does work as expected.
PHP_COMMAND="php -d 'include_path=/path/to/dir'"
echo "$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'"
$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'
```

Script also available online: http://gist.github.com/276500

Comment: You should also read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a simpler way, but one fix is to surround the entire command line with double quotes and then eval that:

```
PHP_COMMAND="php -d 'include_path=/path/with spaces/dir'"
eval "$PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'"
```

Comment: ok wow cool! that's a good start.

It's a solution, but it's not an answer to my question (which I think you realize).

Since the script that runs the command is a third-party script, I'd like a solution that doesn't require munging the third-party script.

But thanks, this is at least a workable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your comments on other answers, I have tried to decipher what you really intended to ask:

> I have an `sh` script that contains the line
>
> ```
> $PHP_COMMAND -r 'echo get_include_path();'
> ```
>
> I can not edit this script, but I need the eventual command line to be (equivalent to)
>
> ```
> php -d include_path='/path/with spaces/dir' -r 'echo get_include_path();'
> ```
>
> How can I achieve this?

If this accurately reflects your situation, then this is one way:

Write another script (I'll call it `/some/path/to/bar.sh`) to use as `PHP_COMMAND`. Since the variable is not quoted in the original script, you will have to make sure that the full pathname of `bar.sh` does not have any shell-special characters (like spaces).

#### /some/path/to/bar.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exec php -d 'include_path=/path/with spaces/dir' ${1+"$@"}
```

Then, to run it, set `PHP_COMMAND`, and run the original script (`/path/to/foo.sh`):

```
env PHP_COMMAND=/some/path/to/bar.sh '/path/to/foo.sh'
```

Comment: You elegantly re-phrased my question. My examples reflected this, but I guess my copy was less precise. I'll see if they let me edit my post.

Your solution is a very interesting idea, that's quite clever.  I will try that out later.

Answer (score 0):

Bash's `printf` has some special secret magic that might help. Try:

```
PHP_COMMAND="php -d $(printf "%q" "'include_path=/path/to/dir'")"
```

or some variation of that.

**Edit:**

I'm sorry, I should have included some explanation and an example. The `%q` flag causes `printf` to add escaping to the string so it can be reused in another command. The output of that `printf` would look like this (the single quotes get escaped):

```
\'include_path=/path/to/dir\'
```

This command illustrates some additional escaping:

```
$ printf "%q" "string ';\ text"
string\ \'\;\\\ text
```

Comment: i am not sure how this helps my problem... the problem occurs when substituted into the final command, not in preparing the "PHP_COMMAND" variable. Could you do a 2-line working example?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried it, but it didn't work. I am still getting the same error. If you could provide a working copy/paste example based on my example that'd be great. Although, you should know I think the 'eval' solution so far seems the simplest so far.

Answer (score -1):

what about this?

```
$PHP_COMMAND ' -r echo get_include_path();'
```